# Script to handle package.json dependency merge conflicts

Tags: git, npm

I'm wondering if anyone has a script that could do the following:

- detect and fix a merge conflict in the dependencies in the package.json file
- always take latest version of the dependency in question

For example:

```
<<<<<<< someBranch
lodash: "1.2.3",
=======
lodash: "1.4.5",
>>>>>>> master
```

I want to take just the `lodash: "1.4.5",` line from the merge conflict.

Thanks!

Comment: _"always take latest version"_ - how would git know? Git doesn't (and shouldn't) care about the semantics of code

Comment: Right, that would be the script analyzing the differing lines in the merge conflict and making a decision as to which version to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an npm module, `fix-package-conflicts` to handle doing this https://github.com/tnrich/fix-package-conflicts:

Here's the example usage:

```
npx fix-package-conflicts pathToYourRepo branchName --useYarn
--incomingBranch=main
```

aka

```
npx fix-package-conflicts ~/Sites/react-snowpack zoinkl --useYarn
--incomingBranch=main
```

```
npx fix-package-conflicts -h                                     
fix-package-conflicts [folderPath] [branch]

Merge in a branch and fix any merge conflicts.

USAGE: fix-package-conflicts ~/Sites/react-snowpack zoinkl --useYarn
--incomingBranch=main

Positionals:
  folderPath  folderPath to fix conflicts at eg ~/Sites/yourRepoName
                                               [default: "~/Sites/yourRepoName"]
  branch      branch to fix conflicts on eg someBranchWithConflicts
                                            [default: "someBranchWithConflicts"]

Options:
      --version         Show version number                            [boolean]
  -h, --help            Show help                                      [boolean]
  -i, --incomingBranch  Set the incoming branch to something other than master
                                                    [string] [default: "master"]
  -y, --useYarn         Run with yarn                                  [boolean]
```

And here's the output from an example run:

```
npx fix-package-conflicts ~/Sites/react-snowpack zoinkl --useYarn
CHECKING OUT /Users/tnrich/Sites/react-snowpack
MERGING master into zoinkl
CONFLICT DETECTED IN FILE: /Users/tnrich/Sites/react-snowpack/package.json
FILE ALREADY FIXED:  /Users/tnrich/Sites/react-snowpack/build/package.json
EXECUTING YARN TO FIX LOCK FILE ...may take a minute...
FINISHED
```